Generate a very plain URL with Actix web which has no further params
How do I supply nothing when generating a URL in Actix web for Rust?
req.request().url_for(website::RESOURCE_LOGIN, nothing_to_go_here);
The url_for method is forcing me to supply an iterator as the second arg.
The URL is just /something. Seems odd to force me to consume memory for nothing.
Here's the sig:
    pub fn url_for<U, I>(&self, name: &str, elements: U) -> Result<url::Url, UrlGenerationError>
    where
        U: IntoIterator<Item = I>,
        I: AsRef<str>,

If I use &[] it needs type annotations, which I'm too noob to know. So I'll supply &[""] and carry on. It seems like it should take an Option.
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
   --> src/lib.rs:100:39
    |
    |         let login_url = req.request().url_for(website::RESOURCE_LOGIN, &[]);
    |                                       ^^^^^^^                          --- type must be known at this point
    |                                       |
    |                                       cannot infer type of the type parameter `U` declared on the method `url_for`
help: consider specifying the generic arguments
    |
    |         let login_url = req.request().url_for::<&[_; 0], &T>(website::RESOURCE_LOGIN, &[]);
    |                                              +++++++++++++++

Okay so the compiler say to use this
::<&[_; 0], &T>

And that leads to this:
102 |             .url_for::<&[_; 0], &T>(website::RESOURCE_LOGIN, &[]);
    |                                  ^ not found in this scope
    |
help: you might be missing a type parameter
    |
92  | async fn check_auth<T>(
    |                    +++

I have no idea what's going on now.

Just using &[] should not consume any memory right?

It needs strings, I'll update the Q

So? &[] is a valid array reference for no strings. Because it's generic you have to supply an actual type like &[] as &[&str] but that's it.

That needs type annotations, which I don't know, because I'm learning.

Just follow the help:.

Face palm. Tbh I just look at the red errors inline in the code editor. I only looked in the build output in order to paste it into this question!!

It still doesn't work. The suggested code just produces a new error. And then I use the suggestion and that produces yet another!

Well you'll have to use real types, any one will do, <&[String; 0], &String>, <&[&str; 0], &&str> you can even omit some part: <&[String; 0], _>, <_, &String>, …

I see a url_for_static method you can use instead. It does exactly what you're after:

This method is similar to HttpRequest::url_for() but it can be used for urls that do not contain variable parts.

For those curious, its implementation looks like this:
pub fn url_for_static(&self, name: &str) -> Result<url::Url, UrlGenerationError> {
    const NO_PARAMS: [&str; 0] = [];
    self.url_for(name, NO_PARAMS)
}


Unfortunately Rust does need to know the type of I and it won't be able to infer it with most generic empty types.
One option that I think looks slightly cleaner than using arrays is this:
url_for("greg", None::<String>);

You still need to uglily specify the type "String" but at least you don't need to specify both the types of U and I seperately.
If you need to use no arguments more often you can specify a seperate type for it:
struct NoUrlArguments;

impl IntoIterator for NoUrlArguments {
    type Item = String;
    type IntoIter = <Option<String> as IntoIterator>::IntoIter;
    
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        None.into_iter()
    }
}

fn main() {
    url_for("david", NoUrlArguments);
}

You can use this type every time you need to use url_for with no arguments.

Thanks to commenters, this is the alternative to supplying an empty string:
.url_for::<&[_; 0], &String>(website::RESOURCE_LOGIN, &[]);


None should also work and might be a bit cleaner, since it will implement IntoIterator which is the required trait.

If you do want to go with an array you should be able to remove the ; 0
